# Hibernate Search - StandardAnalyzer with empty stopwords via persistence.xml

Tags: hibernate-search

I've a question regarding the configuration of `Hibernate Search` via persistence.xml . The standard analyzer used for indexing and searching is the `StandardAnalyzer`. This analyzer has a list of english stopwords per default. I know that via constructor this stopword-list can be replaced with an own list (or EMPTY_SET). Unfortunately I didn't find such an option in the official documentation. The only thing I found is that it's possible to set a different analyzer via the `hibernate.search.analyzer` property. My question: is there an existing property to deactivate the english stopwords while using the `StandardAnalyzer`?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You could define your own subclass of `StandardAnalyzer`, pass the parameters you want to the super constructor, and set the `hibernate.search.analyzer` property to the fully qualified classname of your subclass.</strike> **EDIT:** As @AnarchoEnte replied, `StandardAnalyzer` is a final class, so you actually cannot do that.

But in my opinion, you'd be better off defining your own analyzer doing exactly what the standard analyzer does, but without stopwords:

```
@AnalyzerDef(
    name = "myDefault",
    tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(
        factory = org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizerFactory.class
    ),
    filters = {
        @TokenFilterDef(
            factory = org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardFilterFactory.class
        ),
        @TokenFilterDef(
            factory = org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.LowerCaseFilterFactory.class
        )
    }
)
public class MyEntity { // The annotation must be on an indexed entity, which one doesn't matter.
...
}
```

Then set it as default analyzer:

```
hibernate.search.analyzer = myDefault
```

This way, if you ever need to change something to the analyzer (add some filters, change the tokenizer, ...) you will only have to change that definition.

Comment: Thanks. Sub-Classing the `StandardAnalyzer` is not possible because the class is final. But defining an own analyzer looks good.

Comment: a comment (,) is missing after the first `@TokenFilterDef(...)`